# Connect to ESC POS device thought wifi/ethernet

Tags: flutter, thermal-printer

```
import 'package:esc_pos_printer/esc_pos_printer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  
  late NetworkPrinter printer;
  void testReceipt() async {
    final PosPrintResult res = await printer.connect('192.168.1.3', port: 9100);

    if (res == PosPrintResult.success) {
      // testReceipt(printer);
      print('ko ket noi');
      printer.disconnect();
    } else {
      print('false');
    }

    printer.text(
        'Regular: aA bB cC dD eE fF gG hH iI jJ kK lL mM nN oO pP qQ rR sS tT uU vV wW xX yY zZ');

    printer.text(
      'Text size 200%',
    );

    printer.feed(2);
    printer.cut();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: testReceipt, child: Text('in demo')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Cannot find the way to connect it. Keep showing errow printer has not been initialized.

I try to search on github and the document and nothing work.
And also, where the ip adrress come from ?
I plugged in the network connection to the computer and printer
So in the code i put ipv4 of my PC is that right ?
The document i found. notthing can run